# Appcelerator Apple Music Api

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I inherited an Appcelerator iOS project and recently made some updates.   Apple rejected my most recent update for the following reason:

*Your app uses the Apple Music API but does not display or appropriately use standard media controls such as "play", "pause", and "skip."*

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that Appcelerator is including the Apple MediaPlayer framework even though my app doesn't play music or invoke Apple Music.

Is there a way I can control which Apple Frameworks Appcelerator builds into the Xcode projects?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this JIRA ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-25424

It is related to your problem and has a custom build of 6.3.1 with a fix.

Another solution would be to explain them that you don't use the framework and can't display the buttons. Use the reply function on the Apple rejection page.

Comment: I have tried explaining the situation to them, but that doesn't seem to matter.   In the next day or two I will try the custom build and report back status.   Thanks!

Comment: you can also just add the description, it doesn't hurt. And... no one will see it anyways